# Sticky Header, Up to a point

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a class "sticky" being added to a div when it reaches the top of the page, turning it's css position to fixed.

When the user reaches the bottom of that portion of the page, I want to remove the sticky class.

That header is only relevant for a portion of the page.

Any thoughts on how to add that to my current code?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var stickyNavTop = $('.header').offset().top;

        var stickyNav = function(){
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
                $('.header').addClass('sticky');
            } else {
                $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
            }
        };

        stickyNav();

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            stickyNav();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/m6q6j8xL/)

use this function to calculate if scrolling reaches to the end of the page

i have added `padding` to the `container` when the `header` changes to `fixed` so the the height of the `document` remains the same

`document height` - `window height` which will give you the value when scrolling reaches last area

```
function scrolling() {
    doc = $(document).height()
    win = $(window).height()
    height = doc - win
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= height) {
        $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.container').css('padding-top', '0');
    }
}
```

**Edit**

changed the function to find if scrolling comes in the range of the `div` and show hide

if scroll comes in the range of blue div it will get normal else it will get `fixed`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6q6j8xL/3/)

```
function scrolling() {
    doc = $(document).height()
    hidingtop = $('.hiding').offset().top;
    hidingbottom = $('.hiding').position().top + $('.hiding').outerHeight(true)
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > hidingtop && $(window).scrollTop() < hidingbottom) {
        $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.container').css('padding-top', '0');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code helped me with another problem I had (my content below was jumping up when the sticky class was added). But this still didn't help me with the problem I'm asking about here; maybe I did something wrong. Please not that all this code is from a partial page that is loaded into index.html using angularjs's routing feature. So I want that sticky class to get removed when the user scrolls past that div that is showing the partial view. I'm sorry it's so complicated to explain but it's such a simple thing once you see it